# Why the logs are empty in laravel telescope?

Tags: laravel

As I understand laravel telescope will read my logs files that are stored in:  **storage/logs** and show it inside laravel telescope's logs section..

But still when I try to see the logs, it always shows me an **empty** entries, even though I have some logs files in the storage..

How can I see the logs in **storage/logs** in laravel telescope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, telescope does not directly read your logs.

I've viewed the LogWatcher class and it turns that any logging event that includes an exception will get ignored. These are stored separately in the exceptions section within telescope. Only logs added via the Log facade will be shown in the log section.

If you'd like to have exceptions shown, then you must define your own LogWatcher.

Comment: @VinceKronlein You're right, it's unclear what that's supposed to mean. With "user-defined logs" I meant any logs added via the Log facade. I shall change my answer promptly.

Thank you for highlighting this.

Comment: Perfect, I figured this is what you meant, but that's definitely more clear now.